# What is the returned value of a compound expression in R?

Tags: r, expression, expression-evaluation

In R, I can do:

```
{1+1; 2+2; 3+3}
```

or, if you prefer:

```
{1+1
 2+2
 3+3}
```

Perhaps not surprisingly, both of these (compound) expressions evaluate to 6.

Is this a (documented) feature of the R language, that the value of a compound expression is equal to the last evaluated statement in the compound expression?

The official documentation is light on the topic: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Compound-expressions

Comment: The answer is yes. Notice that cited section correctly predicts results of `is.function(` applied to a back-ticked `{`, i.e.`TRUE`. You can also use this to demonstrate that the tilde-operator (`~`) is also parsed as a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that this is in fact the documented behavior:
http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Evaluation-of-expression-objects

Comment: The other clue is that in the original link you provided is says that "internally, [compound expressions are] stored as a function call" and functions return the result of the last evaluated expression.